# Generating WSDL in Symfony2

Tags: php, web-services, symfony, soap

I am following [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_services/php_soap_extension.html) documentation to create a web service in Symfony, but this line is killing me:

```
$server = new \SoapServer('/path/to/hello.wsdl');
```

Ok, I need to create the WSDL by myself. So I began reading how to achieve that with NuSOAP but I have no idea how to integrate it correctly with Symfony.

Also I've tried the BeSimpleSoapBundle, I followed [that](http://besim.pl/SoapBundle/soapserver/configuration.html) documentation, but this error prompts me:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'BeSimple\SoapWsdl\Dumper\Dumper' not found in /var/www/eCommerce/PFeCommerce/vendor/besimple/soap-bundle/BeSimple/SoapBundle/WebServiceContext.php line 87

So...I have no clue about creating a WebService server in Symfony..any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is simple: the constructor of SoapServer expects to found the WSDL in /web folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add this: https://packagist.org/packages/besimple/soap-wsdl to your composer.json and update it.

Comment: For now I want to write my own WSDL so I don't need any WSDL generator, the problem is the line '$server = new \SoapServer('/path/to/hello.wsdl');', I tried to pass a correct filesystem path to my WSDL file but didn't work. Also I tried to pass a correct URL but it didn't work too.